# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on boolean in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello I am uploading file in laravel but i found following error
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on boolean

```
if($property_brochure=$request->file('property_brochure') && $property_rera_certificate=$request->file('property_rera_certificate'))

         {

 

                 $brochure=$property_brochure->getClientOriginalName();

                 $property_brochure->move('admin_assets/images/property_brochure/',$brochure);

                 $certificate=$property_rera_certificate->getClientOriginalName();

                 $property_rera_certificate->move('admin_assets/images/property_rera_certificate/',$certificate);

                 $property->property_brochure=$brochure;

                 $property->property_rera_certificate=$certificate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong, Please try this if it works or not

```
if($request->hasFile('property_brochure') && $request->hasFile('property_rera_certificate')) {
       $property_brochure= $request->file('property_brochure');
       $property_rera_certificate= $request->file('property_rera_certificate');
       $brochure=$property_brochure->getClientOriginalName();
       $property_brochure->move('admin_assets/images/property_brochure/',$brochure);
       $certificate=$property_rera_certificate->getClientOriginalName();
       $property_rera_certificate->move('admin_assets/images/property_rera_certificate/',$certificate);
       $property->property_brochure=$brochure;
       $property->property_rera_certificate=$certificate;
}
```

For further information, [please read](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)